# Matlab compiler compatible with R

Tags: r, matlab

I have a lot of code in Matlab, and I want to make that available through a package in R.

I have a Matlab compiler. The problem seems to be that the C compiler for Matlab is not compatible with the C compiler for R

I am aware of the different ways of calling Matlab from R, or submitting Matlab code through R to a server.

What i need is different; i want to call a library compiled in Matlab from R

Comment: We probably need more details (what compilers, what versions, where specifically are you running into problems?)  One possible (ugly) workaround would be to include an executable binary blob in your package (although this would preclude you from making it available on CRAN)

Comment: the Matlab C compilers that are available are: Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Professional
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Professional SP1
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Professional SP1 and Windows SDK 6.1 1 2
the problem that I run into is that when i load the library in R, i cannot see the 'table names'. so yes, the temp fix i work with is to   include a big ugly executible

Answer (score 1):

You can [select what compiler MATLAB should use](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html) when compiling to C code:

```
mex -setup
```

I don't know how you would set up your compiler in R, but if you're asking "can I select the C compiler in MATLAB to match the C compiler I have in R", the answer may be **yes**. This of course depends on [whether or not the compiler you wish to use is compatible with MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/index.html).